# Grouping multiple elements with the same class

Tags: jquery, class, grouping

This is a follow-up question related to this thread...
[jQuery - Grouping multiple elements with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270595/jquery-grouping-multiple-elements-with-the-same-class/48892720?noredirect=1#comment84790941_48892720)

Question:
Thanks for the code above. How can I modify this piece if I have multiple classes in the div? For eg:

class="div1 section-1"

class="div2 section-1"

I still need to combine all the section classes like in the example but I have an additional class for each div.

Comment: @the-alpha...Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer.. hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Get all the classes
  var classes = $('[class*=section]').map(function() {
    var section = $.grep(this.className.split(" "), function(v, i) {
      return v.indexOf('section-') === 0;
    }).join()
    return section;
  });

  // Filter only unique ones
  var uniqueClasses = $.unique(classes);

  // Now group them
  $(uniqueClasses).each(function(i, v) {
    $('.' + v).wrapAll('<div class ="parent-' + v + '"></div>');
  });
});
```

```css
div[class*=section] {
  background: #fd6548;
  margin: 10px;
}

div[class*=parent-section] {
  background: #dd5500;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1 section-2">a</div>
<div class="div1 section-1">b</div>
<div class="div2 section-1">c</div>
<div class="div2 section-2">d</div>
```

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you so much. It was exactly what I needed. Works perfectly.